# Can mongodb replicasets be used safely for resource redundancy over the internet?

Tags: python, mongodb, kivy, client-server, replicaset

I am working on a multi-platform (desktop, mobile, eventually web) software suite in Python+Kivy/Django, with MongoDB for the backend, that require some redundancy to ensure resources are always available. I am thinking of using mongodb's replication platform in order to make these resources available locally and remotely.

Local/offline availability is a must, most functionalities can't be internet reliant/web based.

Remote/online availability is desirable for backup/fallback and some functionalities for remote data tracking.

So i was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Local
|-ClientApp (consumes from local)
|-Server (primary+secondary mongodb nodes)

Online
|-Server (multiple secondary nodes)

Remote
|-ClientApp (consumes from online)
```

I know this is possible.
But I wonder what would be the best approach  to implement this.
Is mongodb's replicasets enough? What kind of security mesures would be advised. I am thinking of using pairing keys (like facebook's API) for the apps, how can this be done with the proposed architecture?

Comment: What will you manage the session with? You must type a separate service into the service (which can be in any language). As a rule, the databases are closed to Internet access. If you think of variations and probabilities, this thought is not good.

Comment: not sure I understand all your questions.. i must admit this is a little out of my comfort zone here.. I have only mostly done local/intranet implementations

Comment: atempting to answer your questions, with my limitations: mongodb manages connections between replicaset members automatically afaik, that is to say that, if a node is down, it'll direct the request to a node that is up. So I wouldnt need to diretly manage this connection or serving the database, I am only thinking of hosting a mongodb instance somewhere.

Comment: maybe I should clarify that I use the term "server" broadly, refering to the a machine hosting mongo instances

Comment: Security, cost (server) should always be considered. These types of transactions are not performed over a normal network. Encrypted tunneling connections are used. The bus and service path must be separate (see how the computer works). Direct access to the data layer is not acceptable. Although data security is important, it is important to actually maintain data integrity. Accessing a data stack from the outside is no different from holding the same data in two different places.